# Homepage not immediately recognizing session PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a site that displays two different versions of a navigation section depending on if a user is logged in or not.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
        echo '<a href="'.$baseRoot.$defaultPage.'?com=logout&cxid='.uniqid(),'">Log Out</a>';
    }else{
        echo '<a href="'.$baseRoot.$defaultPage.'?com=login&cxid='.uniqid(),'" class="signupbutton">Sign Up</a>';
    }
?>
```

The problem happens when a user is logged in and then closes the browser without logging out (and assuming they don't clear cache/cookies on browser exit).

When they open their browser later and come back to the site, the navigation displays as if they're not logged in. If they then click a link elsewhere on the site, i.e. *My Account*, the navigation then changes to show that they are logged in.

Any ideas what could be causing this?  I'd like the navigation to show that they're logged in immediately upon coming back to the site.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of every page?

Comment: Does your site have a `keep me logged in/remember me` feature?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, check `session_start()` appears on your pages before any html, even the !DOCTYPE rule.

Now, on your index page add this:

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  header("location: home.php"); // or whatever page you want your users to be redirected to... 

  }else {
  ?>
  //  here your html page should start 
  <html><head></head><body>
  // all the DOM elements on your page
  </body></html>
  <?php  
   } // closing end of the else block started above  
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be as below.

```
ob_start();
session_start();
//code to check session and other
```

`ob_start()` is for omitting header already sent error.